# Why are graphics on iPad Retina pixelated?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air, retina-display

I'm currently developing Flash using AIR 3.2 for iOS. I've set the stage size to 2048 by 1536px. The resolution in publish settings is also set to 'High'. How come graphics, sprites, images, etc, are pixelated?! They don't look pixelated when tested on an iPod Touch (retina) or iPhone. I'm totally stumped on this... there's no reason why it should be pixelated! Please help!

I know that the iPod Touch/iPhone have 326ppi whereas the iPad has 264ppi. I've even resized images and graphics to accommodate for this but this is not the problem. They look pixelated on the iPad!

Have I got a setting wrong or something? Or is there a bit of code I need that I'm missing...?

Comment: Maybe your eyes are just REALLLY good :)

Comment: ...They actually are pixelated. When compared to other apps or even the detail of icons on the iPad, it looks aliased or something.

Comment: Are you using Flex? If so, are you setting an `applicationDPI`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AIR's pixel doubling as suggested by JustLogin was the problem. It appears that using AIR SDK 3.2 and BELOW will have this issue. So basically I was viewing all graphics and everything on stage as Non-Retina, on a Retina display. Retina is not fully supported on 3.2 so it publishes it as Non-Retina, even when set to High resolution. The best solution is to update the AIR SDK to 3.3 or ABOVE. I updated to 3.7 and it works fine now.

Comment: This makes sense as support for the Retina iPad was not added until 3.3. Prior to 3.3, it read the DPI as 132, the iPad 1/2 DPI. So it created a 132 DPI stage and the device scaled the app up to the actual DPI. You should have seen pixelation throughout the entire app (minus, maybe, text), not just on images.

Answer (score 2):

[This guide](http://www.richardlord.net/blog/using-the-ipad-retina-display-with-adobe-air) may help you. It's about AIR's pixel doubling on iPad.

Comment: Does this mean that even if I set the stage size to 2048 by 1536px in Flash, it will still be publishing the stage as 1024 by 768px?

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things I would consider:

1. Are your images looking ok when you open them with an image viewer ?
2. Are your images resized/scaled programmatically ? if yes, that may be one reason.
3. Are you placing your images as fixed int positions ? ex. non int values like

   img.x = 20.383; and img.y = 65.884 // will cause troubles

Comment: Yeah that images look fine in an image viewer. For example, an icon which was 150 by 150px on iPod Touch/iPhone is resized to 122 by 122px  for iPad Retina, because of the ppi difference, to make it look physically the same size. They are all round numbers and not resized/scaled programmatically. Even imported text, or default text looks pixelated for some reason on the iPad? Sprites (such as circles) are the same.